# MS Word RibbonX How can I dynamically populate a combobox when a dotm file opens?

Tags: vba, dynamic, combobox, ms-word, ribbon

I'm a little stumped here. I'm diving deeper into designing ribbons for MS Word 2010, and I came across something new: populating comboboxes on the fly. In the image below, you can see...

[image: MS Word 2010 custom ribbon with unpopulated combobox]

...that I'm a dude who likes music while he works, just like any other dude. Problem is my list of playlists changes from time to time, so I don't want to hard-code that list into my ribbon's combobox. I can easily hard-code it, but I want this thing to be dynamic. And so, in my ribbon code:

```
    <comboBox id="cmbPLaylist" label="Playlist" getItemLabel="Document_Open">
        <item id="none" label="None"/>
    </comboBox>
```

I have left only one item, "none," which is fine if I want the music player to launch with no playlist loaded. But what if I want a playlist to automatically load?

First, from my Google and book research, I've determined that I need to have a getItemLabel callback to populate the control. Is this the right way to go? But how do I run that automatically when my Normal.dotm loads? I'm having problems running this thing in the Document_Open event, and I've been reading online that I'm not alone.

My problem is a bit threefold: first, I'm really new at using these predefined callbacks like getEnabled, getItemLabel, etc. The callback territory is a very new territory for me. Second, I've never used a combobox in a ribbon before. Three, I've never dynamically populated a combobox in a ribbon before. I might be trying to bite off more than I can chew at once, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

My code so far, inserted into my Normal.dotm Document_Open event, is such:

```
Private Sub Document_Open(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    Dim ListOfPlaylists() As String

    ListOfPlaylists = GetPlaylists()
    ListOfPlaylists(UBound(ListOfPlaylists)) = "Random"
End Sub
```

After this, I'm stumped. As you can see, I'm not sure how to tell MS Word, "Hey, MS Word, insert this value into the combobox list!"

Maybe it's my newbness at this whole thing, but when I Google for an answer, I'm not seeing it in the code. So any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a hunch, but doesn't something like this work: `For i=0 to UBound(ListOfPlaylists) : cmbPlaylist.AddItem ListOfPlaylists(i) : Next`

Comment: Ahhh, were to start... Dynamic content of the RIbbon is controlled by the RIbbonXML. You need to use "get" attributes - and NO static elements. The "get" attributes point to *callbacks* (`Public Sub` with the correct arguments) in the document that contains the Ribbon. These get executed the first time when the Ribbon is loaded, automatically. IF you set things up correctly, at that first loading, a callback for the entire Ribbon can populate a variable for the Ribbon that can be used at any later point to force a certain control or the entire Ribbon to again execute the "get" callbacks.

Comment: The fact that I need to start an additional comment to finish this "intro" is an indication that your question is "too broad" for this site. But the concepts are odd for people with VBA experience... I recommend you work through the MSDN article Customize the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for developers (1 of 3) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12) as your next step. Pay special attention to the topic "Ribbon Customization Scenarios for other Applications". Here you'll find some examples for using dynamic callbacks, including for a dropdown list.

Comment: Use the above to get a start on the basic principle. Then you can come back with a more specific question if you run into roadblocks. Additonal resource: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ba8c9d0b-7312-4503-8167-f2ef86f17435/information-on-the-office-fluent-ui-ribbon-for-developers?forum=officegeneral has a list of articles on using the Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did some fiddling and almost stumbled on the answer. I put this in my code and it seems to work just fine now:

```
Sub drpPlaylists_getItemCount(Control As IRibbonControl, ByRef drpPlaylists_itemCount)
    drpPlaylists_itemCount = UBound(ReadDirectoryContents(MusicDirectory, "*.m3u"))
End Sub
```

I guess this gets launched every time the ribbon has to reload itself. But it's solved for now. Still have some things to study up on on when these callbacks get called, but I'll figure this out. Thanks for the help!